# Uniqueness of Complement Subspace Decomposition

Tags: vector-spaces

Let W be a subspace of V. A subspace Z of V is called a complementary subspace of W if

i)$W\cap Z = \emptyset$.

ii)$W+Z=V$, that is every $v\in V$ can be written as $v=w+z$ for $w\in W$ and $z\in Z$.

Prove that if $v=w+z$ then $w\in W$ and $z\in Z$ are uniquely determined.

My attempt:

Let $w_1, w_2 \in W$, $z_1, z_2 \in Z$, assume $w_1 \neq w_2$, $z_1 \neq z_2$. Then $w_1 + z_1 = w_2 + z_2$.

And I don't know how to proceed after that. I'm familiar with uniqueness proofs, but I don't know how to apply it to this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$w_1-w_2=z_2-z_1$. Since $Z$ and $W$ are subspaces the left side belongs to $W$ and the right side to $Z$. Hence they belong to $Z \cap W=\{0\}$ which gives $z_1=z_2$ and $w_1=w_2$.